# Trigger page fault manually for mmap() memory, for long sequence of random reads

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, concurrency, linux-kernel

I am writing an application which `mmap()` a huge file into memory, and for a given user input performs a long sequence of deterministic random reads on the file. A rough outline:

```
int* data = mmap(HugeFile);

int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0, ptr = UserInput(); i < LargeNumber; i++)
{
    sum += data[ptr];
    ptr = DeterministicCalculation(ptr);
}
```

The application is slowed down because of frequent page faults. And because the next page fault is triggered only after the previous one completes, I am not able to saturate disk IO on an SSD.

Preferably, I want to do something like

```
for (int i = 0, ptr = UserInput(); i < LargeNumber; i++)
{
    AsyncPageFault(data[ptr]);
    ptr = DeterministicCalculation(ptr);
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could spawn multiple threads to each handle a subset of the reads?

Comment: Would the `madvise` function help? Or the `posix_madvise` function?

Comment: @wxz Yes I can. But I want to check if there is a way to do memory management in the kernel instead of userspace.

Comment: @IanAbbott I read the manpage and it seems that `MADV_WILLNEED` is close to what I need :-) I also found a realworld usage in Firefox: http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1004.0/01688.html